# How to stop ALL tests if a certain exception is thrown

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

Occasionally throughout the day, developers do builds which will give you a 404 error when trying to log into the web application.

I have a simple condition during the Login portion of the Selenium code that will throw an exception if the environments are undergoing a build. I can catch the exception but what I want is to stop the execution of ALL of the other tests. (I have over 40 tests that don't need to run if a department is doing a build).

Answer (score 0):

Put the logic that makes the check and throws the exception in the OneTimeSetUp method of a SetUpFixture. If the fixture is outside of any namespace, the method will run before any tests and will fail all of them. If it's in some namespace, it will run before the tests in that namespace and fail only those.

If you prefer some other outcome besides failure, make the comparison explicitly and use Assert.Ignore or Assert.Inconclusive.